# What additional features are available in latest Solr (upgrade from Solr 3) when used in Tridion 8.5

Tags: dxa, search, solr

We currently use Solr version 3 in Tridion 2013 SP1. We are migrating the Solr and Tridion to latest versions (Web 8.5 and Solr 7.0). What are the latest features we should mainly concentrate to make our search for a better performance than the earlier versions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From Tridion's perspective, the following points are relevant:

- What "type" is your website application, the tag
  says DXA, is this correct?
- Are you using Solr for your website search?

  - If yes, how are you populating Solr?

But even then, this doesn't look like a Tridion specific question per se. I suggest you take a look at the following [**article**](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/tips-and-tricks-to-maximize-apache-solr-performance-74e8ea4f5c8d) on how to improve Solr performance. And the following [**article**](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/major-changes-in-solr-7.html) on the changes and upgrade planning in Solr 7.